# Detecting scroll in vue.js

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, methods

I wanted to fire a function in vue.js when scrolling is detected or even better fire a function when scrolling is over say 5% of the windowsize or something like that. But I cannot get it right.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Test1 v-on:scroll.passive="handleScroll"></Test1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Test1 from "./Test1";

export default {
  name: "HomePage",
  components: {
    Test1
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll: function() {
      alert("something");
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style >
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with vue - do you want to track the entire page scroll or scrolling in some sub element?

Comment: I want to track the the scrolling in my component I guess ...

Comment: might be able to adapt something like this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/whquxfjy/

Comment: thanks. I could handle it in jquery though but I am new to vue.js so not really sure how to implement it in vue.js. Looking for a way to implement it there. It is probably not to difficult but I cannot get it right ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event and fire your function when needed

```
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        if(e.pageY>window.innerHeight*0.05){
            console.log('over 5%'); //use your function here
        }
    });
```

Make sure you remove the event listener when you don't need it anymore or your component unmounts

Comment: Thanks. What is the different from this method compared to something like this. ` <my-component v-on:scroll.native="handleScroll"> ` . And what if I want to detect scrolling in a specific component?

Comment: See https://forum.vuejs.org/t/for-v-on-aspecificevent-is-it-necessary-to-create-destroy-event-listeners/40688/6: "A custom component, as just a calling syntax beacon, is not a component that can emit an event but can forward an event from within it. Only native components can emit a native event."